# how to discover an angle between two objects?

Tags: java, android, math, angle

what I want to do is the following: I have an object (blue point) and I want to point it to other object no matter where it is located around it (green point). So I need to know the angle between these two objects to do what I want right?

http://s13.postimage.org/6jeuphcdj/android_angle.jpg

The problem is, I don't know what to do to achieve this. I've already used atan, math.tan and so many other functions but without any good results.

Could you help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post your existing code with atan or math.tan ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the coordinates of the blue and green points are (xblue, yblue) and (xgreen, ygreen) respectively.

The angle at which the blue point sees the green point is:

```
double angleRadians = Math.atan2(ygreen-yblue, xgreen-xblue);
```

If you want the angle in degrees:

```
double angleDegrees = Math.toDegrees(angleRadians);
```

Answer (score 1):

Calculate a dot product of object vectors. Use `Math.acos` on the value you get. That will give you an angle in radians.

So, say your blue dot is at `vec1 = (50, 100)` and green one at `vec2 = (100, 400)`.

A tuple `(x, y)` as a two dimensional vector describes object's position and distance from `(0, 0)` on your screen. To find the angle between these two vectors, you do a standard, binary dot product operation on them. This will get you a scalar (a value, `cos(Theta)`), but you want the inverse of it (`acos`) which is the angle you're looking for.

You can get a better understanding on the matter [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Geometric_interpretation)

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you mean with a dot product of object vectors?

Comment: This is not the angle OP is looking for. Apart from that this answer is wrong: Either those object vectors have to be unit vectors or you have to normalie them first. Furthermore it's not the inverse of that scalar what you are looking for (which would be just its reciprocal), but the fiber of this scalar under `cos()`

Comment: Depends how the dot product is implemented. They need not be explicitly normalized. However, I don't see the error in my description regarding inverse of a `cos`. Can you please point exactly where I got it wrong? And what is your understanding of the problem?

Comment: Oh okay, now I see it. I haven't looked at the picture at the time I was writing this. I'll leave my answer nevertheless, it might help someone.